# Changing one property in multidimensional array changes other array's properties too

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a multidimensional array called `SensorGetResult`. In some cases this array can have a single array in it. If that happens, I must copy this one array and add it again, so I must have 2 arrays now. Then I need to change these array's `dateTime` property. This is my code:

```
var helperArray = sensorGet.SensorGetResult[0];
sensorGet.SensorGetResult.Add(helperArray);
sensorGet.SensorGetResult[0].dateTime = end; //It works correctly including this line
sensorGet.SensorGetResult[1].dateTime = start; //At this line both array's dateTime property changes
```

Why can't I assign `dateTime` properties to each array individually?

Comment: Look at the `reference type` specifics.

Comment: What's the type of `helperArray`?

Comment: @Imantas It's an associative array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) for your `helperArray`.

When the following code executes:

```
var helperArray = sensorGet.SensorGetResult[0];
sensorGet.SensorGetResult.Add(helperArray);
```

What actually happens is you take a the first element of `SensorGetResult` **which is a reference** to the object (which I believe you intend to copy) and append the reference to the list thus resulting in a list which has two references to the same object in the memory.

If you want it to make a copy of the object, you have to implement that by yourself. Usually this means creating a new object of the same type and copying all the properties.

```
var objectToCopy = sensorGet.SensorGetResult[0];
var helperArray = new WhatEverTypeIsYourHelperArray {
    Property1 = objectToCopy.Property1,
    Property2 = objectToCopy.Property2,
    // etc.
};
sensorGet.SensorGetResult.Add(helperArray);
```

But you have to be aware if any of the properties is furthermore a **reference type**, you need to do this recursively for all the properties.

If `WhatEverTypeIsYourHelperArray` is type you own, you could utilize [Object.MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and make it all easier for yourself. You can do this by implementing a method like the following. As a note, `MemberwiseClone` is a protected method hence the need of a new method in your class.

```
public WhatEverTypeIsYourHelperArray Clone() {
    return (WhatEverTypeIsYourHelperArray)this.MemberWiseClone();
}
```

But even the `MemberwiseClone()` method doesn't copy reference types for you, rather just copies the pointers to the objects which means that all the properties of *reference type* of both the original and the cloned object will point to the same objects in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

SensorGetResult row seems to be a reference type.
So when you wrote

```
var helperArray = sensorGet.SensorGetResult[0];
sensorGet.SensorGetResult.Add(helperArray);
```

you actually said that new row in SensorGetResult will point to the same object as the first one.
You can implement method like below:

```
public SensorGetResultRow  Clone()
{
    return new SensorGetResultRow (this.field1, this.field2, etc...)
    //or if you use parameterless constructor
    return new SensorGetResultRow ()
    {
        field1 = this.field1
        //etc.
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
var helperArray = sensorGet.SensorGetResult[0].Clone();
```